# How does these Python imports work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, flask

I'm just started to learning backend web development using Python from a tutorial [here][1].

The first project is a simple *Hello World* respond to requests for website home page.

Whole the program for above project is consist of 3 files:

```
myWebsite/
    app/
        __init__.py
        views.py
    run.py
```

And the Python files are as below :

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask (__name__)
from app import views
```

**views.py**

```
from app import app
@app.route ('/')
def sayHello():
    return "Hello World"
```

**run.py**

```
from app import app
app.run (debug = True)
```

---

**My origin question:**

The program will execute by interpreting `run.py`. As far as I know in the first line of this file, `from app import app`, it search `__init__.py` for an object named `app` and if it found, make a it available for the next lines, right? 
Well, that seems OK for me (I think!).

The question is, why we need to `from app import app` in `views.py` while I don't want to execute it! I mean I just want to use this file in my `__init__.py` file, so I think that enough to import it in `__init__.py` and I don't need to `from app import app` in `views.py`. Am I wrong?

---

As a side question :

When I write `from x import y`, what is `x` and  what is `y`?

- Is `x` a directory or a file?
- Is `y` a file or an object in a file named `__init__.py`?

When I write `import z`, what is `z`? a file or an object inside one of the libraries?

---

*I know that my question seems simple for experts, but I migrate from C to Python, and look at `import` like #include in C and I think this is origin of my problem. I read some Q&A in SO related to my issue, but I am confused about it yet.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python relative imports for the billionth time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: In `views.py` you need `app` because you use the decorator `app.route`.

Comment: @Matthias But I don't call `views.py` directly. I use content of it in `__init__.py` only

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you. I correct it. It was `from app import view`

Comment: What's wrong with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)?

Comment: Btw, if you're new to Python, I recommend you to use Python 3 instead of Python 2. Flask seems to be pretty much support Python 3 fine, so you'll be better of learning Python 3.